# How does a proper antichronous transformation change the geodesic equation?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor

I want to apply a proper antichronous transformation to the geodesic equation in General Relativity and check if it is even or odd.

Comment: What is your definition of an antichronous transformation in General Relativity? Isn’t this a particular kind of Lorentz transformation in *Special* Relativity? General Relativity does not have global Lorentz transformations.

Comment: Geodesic equation is a tensor quantity being zero. If you apply *Cartan involution* (a term more appropriate for GR than “antichronous transformation”) the equation will still be zero. So what kind of parity are you expecting here?

Comment: @Ghoster I refer to a PT transformation. See an example of proper antichronous transformation applied to GR here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4937

Comment: I don’t believe that paper. According to [this](https://home.uni-leipzig.de/tet/?page_id=281), “Generic curved spacetimes do not, in general possess any symmetries, including symmetries analogous to $P$ and $T$.”

Comment: @Ghoster Then, I just want to know what happens to the geodesic equation when coordinates x and t are reversed.